# Nitpick: Comment character length limit is less than 600 when you include a URL longer than 24 characters

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, character-limit

Because the URL is shortened... count the characters below

Comment: 012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
http://thisurlhassomelongcharacters.com/limit/here1

Comment: And a very small nit at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shortening is cosmetic, not actually written to the db, so this behavior is correct and by design.