# Do not consider characters in links or markup for Comment text

Tags: feature-request, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nitpick: Comment character length limit is less than 600 when you include a URL longer than 24 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/nitpick-comment-character-length-limit-is-less-than-600-when-you-include-a-url)

It seems that link text is considered for determining the length of a comment. Although that might be nice for evading the lower character-limit, it is quite a burden when bumping up against the upper character-limit. Please consider ignoring link and markup characters for purposes of determining comment length.

Comment: Your comments shouldn't really be that long in the first place.  If you are including loads of markdown and content in your comments perhaps you should consider simply updating your post with the added information.

Comment: Then just leave a short comment saying - "please see my updates".

Comment: Thank you Lix, but in my last particular case, editing the question was not the correct course of action. Answering in a comment was the correct course of action, however one of the links that I wanted to add to the comment was exceptionally long. I suppose that I could use a URL shortener service, but I find those redundant and unreliable.

Comment: Is there anything that is preventing you from splitting your comment into two?

Comment: Especially as the link is then "truncated" if you leave it in it's raw state anyway.

Comment: [_](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155556/amanap-lanac-a-nalp-a-nam-a)

Comment: The heck is RFE?

Comment: @Won't probably Request For Enhancement

Comment: As an aside: note the [magic links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000) and [tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71998/tag-should-work-in-comments/94180#94180), allowing for [very long comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment318407_3122). But that probably doesn't help you.

Comment: http://Only-for-markdownified-links-or-for-all-links? http://And bare links with non-breaking spaces? (`http://And bare links with non-breaking spaces` that is...)

Comment: @ConradFrix: TAGS IN TITLES!!!!