# Is chat Feeds bot broken?

Tags: support, bug, feed, russian-stackoverflow, chatbot

Recently I saw a @Feeds bot [message in the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37025953#37025953) for an answer on ruSO.meta:

> [image: answer]

This format is totally different from what it was before. E.g. for question:

> [image: question-ok]

What happened?

Looks Ok for a another answer on the same question:

> [image: answer-ok]

Comment: Was that first post deleted?

Comment: @Catija nope. Link is still active. You could try it yourself.

Comment: You don't list the link... You have the link to the chat transcript and that's it. I'm not interested in bouncing all over SE just to see if a question is active or not.

Comment: @Catija if you want a direct link from the Feeds message here it is: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5167/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-lambda/5168#5168

Comment: My guess would be some character in that title is escaping the regex check matching which URLs are questions & answers - will ping balpha to look this week. Because I such at regex and openly admit it.

Comment: @NickCraver I'm not sure about problem with the title, because title for an answer is used from the question. But question block looks fine in the chat. Another thought this is happened due to my edit of the answer during grace period. I added a link to the Grundy's comment. But I'm not sure about it too.

Comment: @alexolut I think you're making a terrible assumption there about questions and answers being the same code path...which they're not :) They're handled separately, one match may be friend while another isn't. Or it could be something else, but never assume!

Comment: @NickCraver Yes. I can only guess because I don't see a code. Using black-box testing I see only two diffs with another (correctly parsed) answers: post was edited during grace period; that was a first answer. I found several same parse problems in chat via searching for [stack2rss](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=stack2rss).

Comment: May be related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287411/what-determines-whether-a-feed-item-becomes-a-post-onebox-in-chat