# How to prevent inline link URL from counting towards comment length limit?

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown, hyperlinks, character-limit

Is there a way to prevent an inline link URL (the one in parentheses) from counting towards the comment's length limit? How? If not, please implement this. Is there another input technique to make only the human-readable portion count?

Comment: And related questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137036/dont-make-urls-and-title-attributes-count-towards-comment-character-limits?rq=1, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287407/can-we-stop-counting-link-text-in-comment-word-counts?rq=1